# Multiple files upload

Tags: java, extjs

I am trying to upload multiple files using `Extjs` and `Java` and I am using " application/x-www-form-urlencoded " content type and get all the data and files' names from `HttpRequest`. And I need to upload may kind of file. It can be a doc type or Image type.
My problem is the following:

1) While giving static file path all the files from that static location will be uploaded  successfully. But I need to upload multiple files from different locations rather than one static location, so please help me as soon as possible..

This is my file upload controller code

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "views/upload.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> create(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> fileUpload = new HashMap();
    boolean success = false;
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        if (headerName.equals("x-file-name")) {
            System.out.println("Header " + headerName);
            System.out.println(request.getHeader(headerName));
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            String data = sb.toString();
            success = copyFile(data, request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
    }
    fileUpload.put("success", success);
    return fileUpload;
}
// open file for input
private boolean openFileInput(File file) {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("File Not Found...!");
        return false;
    }
}
// copies file
private boolean copyFile(String fileData, String fileName) {
    File file = new File("C://Documents and Settings/infosoft03/Desktop/"
            + fileName);
    //dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));

    // File file = new File(fileName);
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        File dir = new File(PropertyReader.getValue("uploadpath"));
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        // org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file,
        // fileData);
        //success = openFileInput(file);
        if (success) {
            success = true;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    PropertyReader.getValue("uploadpath") + fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            System.out.println("file length" + b.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                b[i] = dis.readByte();
            }
            dos.write(b);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return success;
    } finally {
        if (dos != null) {
            closeOutputStream(dos);
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            closeOutputStream(fos);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```